# Mako template sum

Tags: python, mako

I have a problem creating a Mako template, which will take a list of numbers and output their sum. Example:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

output:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5
```

I want the list to be passed as an argument to the template.
Is the way to go around this using python `' + '.join(list)`?
I know that we can use `\` to escape new line characters and so I could do it in the loop but then special care needs to be taken with regard to the last `+`, which is quite ugly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Built in function `sum()` should work just fine, see [Python doc for sum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum)

Your template body should contain just

`def template(context, numbers_list):
    return sum(numbers_list)`

Or, if numbers get passed in as string:

`def template(context, numbers_list):
    return sum(int(x) for x in numbers_list)`

Comment: I do not need to sum the numbers but to print them with `+` signs between them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, take note that you should **never** name your variables after built-in types.
I am referring to your naming your list (`[1,2,3,4,5]`) as `list` . This can cause a lot of problems.

Secondly, you can use this code to get your desired result :

```
def return_desired_result_():
    li=[1,2,3,4,5]
    x=''
    for i in range(len(li)) :
    if i < len(li) -1 :
        x += str(li[i]) + " + "
    else :
        x += str(li[i])
    return x
```

The code is quite hacky and self explanatory , if however you need any more explanation, just comment.

Comment: Thank you for this. Good point with the variable names. and equivalent python code to do this is `' + '.join(li)`, however, I was looking for a neat way of doing this in Mako.

Comment: `'+'.join(li)` returns `'1+2+3+4+5+'` while my function returns 
`'1+2+3+4+5'`

I thought this was your problem

Comment: no, join takes care of this and does not put the trailing +.

Comment: oh, sorry for the inconvenience  then! :)